# How can I use Caps Lock as Num Lock on my Mac?

Tags: macos, keyboard

The wireless Apple keyboard and the laptops don't have a numeric keypad. While [KeyRemap4Macbook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) provides a virtual numpad, it requires  <kbd>Fn</kbd> to be pressed while using it.

Is it possible to use the *Caps Lock* key (which I never use) for laptop-style *Num Lock* equivalent functionality, i.e. to get a number pad using regular letter keys while it's *active*?

<sup>Inspired by [NumLock app](http://numlockapp.com/), which will require additional software to run, but won't require replacing the Caps Lock key functionality.</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also change caps lock to F19 with PCKeyboardHack and then add this to [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) in KeyRemap4MacBook:

```
<item>
  <name>numpad</name>
  <identifier>numpad</identifier>
  <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F19, KeyCode::VK_LOCK_EXTRA1</autogen>
  <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::M, ModifierFlag::EXTRA1, KeyCode::KEYPAD_0</autogen>
  <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::COMMA, ModifierFlag::EXTRA1, KeyCode::KEYPAD_COMMA</autogen>
  <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::DOT, ModifierFlag::EXTRA1, KeyCode::KEYPAD_DOT</autogen>
  <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::SLASH, ModifierFlag::EXTRA1, KeyCode::KEYPAD_PLUS</autogen>
  <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::J, ModifierFlag::EXTRA1, KeyCode::KEYPAD_1</autogen>
  <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::K, ModifierFlag::EXTRA1, KeyCode::KEYPAD_2</autogen>
  <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::L, ModifierFlag::EXTRA1, KeyCode::KEYPAD_3</autogen>
  <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::SEMICOLON, ModifierFlag::EXTRA1, KeyCode::KEYPAD_MINUS</autogen>
  <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::U, ModifierFlag::EXTRA1, KeyCode::KEYPAD_4</autogen>
  <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::I, ModifierFlag::EXTRA1, KeyCode::KEYPAD_5</autogen>
  <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::O, ModifierFlag::EXTRA1, KeyCode::KEYPAD_6</autogen>
  <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::P, ModifierFlag::EXTRA1, KeyCode::KEYPAD_MULTIPLY</autogen>
  <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEY_7, ModifierFlag::EXTRA1, KeyCode::KEYPAD_7</autogen>
  <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEY_8, ModifierFlag::EXTRA1, KeyCode::KEYPAD_8</autogen>
  <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEY_9, ModifierFlag::EXTRA1, KeyCode::KEYPAD_9</autogen>
  <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEY_0, ModifierFlag::EXTRA1, KeyCode::KEYPAD_SLASH</autogen>
</item>
```

See the source for the [key code values](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/src/bridge/generator/keycode/data/KeyCode.data) and [predefined settings](http://raw.github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/master/Tests/lib/string/data/checkbox.xml).

Answer (score 2):

Download and run the [Ukelele keyboard layout editor](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele). Select *File » New From Current Input Source* to load your current keyboard layout (e.g. *British*).

Now, press *Caps Lock*. You'll see that the Caps Lock key on the virtual keyboard in Ukele will be highlighted, and all letter keys appear in upper case.

Double-click each of the letter keys you want to change. A character assignment dialog pops up. Type the number you want to assign to that key and confirm. Optionally, you can also delete all letters from the rest of the keys (i.e. remove output from the assignment dialog and confirm).

Now, assign a new name (e.g. *British with Caps Lock Numpad*) and ID (e.g. 10000 + original ID) using *Keyboard » Set Keyboard Name* and *Keyboard » Set Keyboard ID*.

[image: Screenshot]

Save the keyboard layout as a file in `~/Library/Keyboard Layouts` and select it in *System Preferences » Language & Text » Input Sources*.

Comment: Keyboard layouts in the user library can't be selected in password dialogs, and the popovers shown when holding keys only work with the bundle format. See the section about custom keyboard layouts in http://lri.me/osx.html.